# Firebird database connection with Zope 4.0 not connecting after upgrade to Zope 4.0

Tags: python, sql, firebird, zope

I truly hope you could help us. We are kind of desperate.

We are upgrading an application from Zope 2.0 to Zope 4.0.

We followed every step in the Zope official documentation https://zope.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrations/zope4/index.html

We are able to start the service and export our Zope objects to Zope 4.0.

Once we upgraded to Zope 4.0 we realized that the DB adapter is not working anymore. Therefore, we had to install a new one which is Products.FirebirdDA.

https://github.com/nakagami/Products.FirebirdDA

The BIG PROBLEM we are having is the follow one:

We successfully created the Firebird Database Connection Object. Once we go inside the DB object it does say on the status tab the connection is open.
[Connection Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUiDW.png)

but if we click on the test tab we get "NAME OF THE OBJECT"(not connected). This is also making our ZSQL Objects to fail once we try to open them.

[DB not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcEzy.png)
[SQL Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC9xF.png)

The issue we do not understand is that if we run queries from the test tabs either on the DB object or the SQL objects the queries run without any inconvenience.

[Success Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwIK0.png)

We have tried to do a lot of research online but unluckily we did not find any answer.

Is anyone able to assist?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to reproduce the problem, and provide sufficient information (e.g. from logs, etc) so it is possible to identify what the problem might be.

Comment: but did you really connect to Firebird, not something else?  `select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version, r.*, m.* from rdb$database r, mon$database m` ?

Comment: I would start with providing database connection string and version of FB server.